# Missing ModulePath and ClassPath on Java, Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

[Eclipse IDE PrintScreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dqgj.png) As you can see in this screenshot, the `ModulePath` and `ClassPath` are missing. I am trying to solve this error:

> Error occurred during initialization of boot layer java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx.controls not found

All the videos I have seen have `ClassPath` and `ModulePath`, why don't I have it?

Comment: For Java 8 and lower, no _Modulepath_ and _Classpath_ nodes are shown since there is only a _Classpath_, but not a _Modulepath_. Fix Java version in _Project > Properties: Java Compiler_.

Comment: To make it clear, your root problem is that you have chosen `CDC-1.0/Foundation-1.0` as the execution environment JRE for your project instead of something like `JavaSE-17`. `CDC-1.0/Foundation-1.0` is much too old to work with JavaFX. [`CDC-1.0/Foundation-1.0`](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=46) is a subset of Java 1.4 which has been released more than 21 years ago, many years before JavaFX. That clearly does not work.

Answer (score -1):

Right click on the project Run As > Run Configurations > dependencies there you will see classpath.